Submit button doesn't refresh page and send POST request
I'm doing registration on Django. I made a form, added a button that should refresh the page and send a POST request. But the button does not update the page and does not send the request. I doesn't have any scripts on JavaScript.
My views.py code:
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import User
from .forms import UserForm
from django.views import View

def index(request): 
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def inn(request):
    return render(request, 'in.html')

class PostCreate(View):    
    def up(self, request):
        form=UserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('home')

    def down(request):
        return render(request, 'up.html')`

My forms.py code:
from .models import User
from django.forms import ModelForm

class UserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=User
        fields=['NickName', 'Email', 'Password']`

And HTML:
HTML
I'm tried to search any information on internet, but I'm found only about event.preventDefault() and type='button'. But I doesn't have any scripts and my type is 'submit'

<field> -> <form>.

I haven't seen def up.  Do you mean def post?

You did not write <form>, but wrote <field> instead, so therefore it does not act like a form at all, and thus the button does not submit.
But that is not the only problem: you used .up(…) and .down(…) as methods in your view. A default view has a .get(…), .post(…) and other HTTP methods as names. You can make the work even more convenient by using a CreateView [Django-doc]:
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView


class PostCreateView(CreateView):
    form_class = UserForm
    template_name = 'up.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')


Note: In Django, class-based views (CBV) often have a …View suffix, to avoid a clash with the model names.
Therefore you might consider renaming the view class to PostCreateView, instead of PostCreate.

